# Calculating Multiple Break in and out in from single column

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Hi i am new to Sql i have one table containing user id Time stamp and Punch type like(in, out m Break in, break out) i would like to have multiple break in and break out to be displayed in one row group by date below is the table structure

```
USERID  CHECKTIME   CHECKTYPE   VERIFYCODE  SENSORID    Memoinfo    WorkCode    sn  UserExtFmt
2175    2018-04-12 17:51:17.000 0   57  120 NULL    0   7408670 0
2175    2018-04-12 17:55:24.000 1   53  120 NULL    0   7408670 0
2175    2018-04-12 17:56:13.000 0   52  120 NULL    0   7408670 0
2175    2018-04-12 17:56:49.000 0   52  120 NULL    0   7408670 0
2175    2018-04-12 17:57:05.000 0   52  120 NULL    0   7408670 0
2175    2018-04-12 18:00:31.000 U   50  120 NULL    0   7408670 0
2175    2018-04-12 18:04:02.000 B   53  120 NULL    0   7408670 0
2175    2018-04-13 05:50:36.000 U   50  120 NULL    0   7408670 0
2175    2018-04-13 05:56:09.000 0   52  120 NULL    0   7408670 0
2175    2018-04-13 05:58:32.000 U   52  120 NULL    0   7408670 0
```

Desired Output

```
Date Break Time1 Breaktime2 Breaktime3 Userid
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: You may want to search for "SQL pivot", and find e.g. [this](https://community.modeanalytics.com/sql/tutorial/sql-pivot-table/) or [this](https://www.clearpeaks.com/pivot-data-in-sql/).

Comment: Try PIVOT TABLE

Comment: And how do you define a "break"?  Nothing in the table says "break".  Are you always limited to three?

Comment: @GordonLinoff the break type is checktype ,"B" means Break in and "U" means Break out